# GROUP_CONCAT - WHERE Condition

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

```
select group_concat(bookgenre), author_authorID
from Written
group by author_authorID;
```

gives me

## table

```
group_conat(bookgenre)      author_authorID
Fiction                     123450
Fiction, History            123451
History                     123457
Sci-Fi                      123458
Fiction                     123459
```

I dont know how to only generation

```
group_concat(bookgenre)     author_authorID
Fiction                     123450
Fiction                     123459
```

When I add the condition

```
where "group_concat(bookgenre)" like 'Fiction'
```

It results with 0 rows returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by

```
select group_concat(bookgenre), author_authorID
from Written
group by author_authorID;
having count(*) = sum(bookgenre = 'Fiction')
```

or use having clause to filter result of aggregate functions

```
select group_concat(bookgenre), author_authorID
from Written
group by author_authorID;
having group_concat(bookgenre) = 'Fiction'
```

Answer (score 0):

Group_concat is an aggregated function so  you should filter using having and not where
And for like you should use wildchar  `%`

```
select group_concat(bookgenre), author_authorID
from Written
group by author_authorID;
havine group_concat(bookgenre) LIKE '%fiction%'
```